# How can I install a beta version of a module?

Tags: 8, composer

Now, a good amount of modules do not yet have a stable version, for example, webform. `composer require drupal/webform` says:

> Could not find package drupal/webform at any version for your minimum-stability (stable). Check the package spelling or your minimum-stability

If I try `composer require --minimum-stability=beta drupal/webform`, I get:

> The "--minimum-stability" option does not exist.

`drush dl` gives:

> This codebase is assembled with Composer instead of Drush. Use `composer update` and `composer require` instead of `drush pm-updatecode` and `drush pm-download`.

Note that due to the special versioning of Drupal this is *not* a generic composer question but a Drupal specific one. Ie. webform today is 8.x-5.0-beta12, how do I install the latest in the 8.x-5.0 series...? Now, composer *doesn't* understand or use 8.x-5.0 but uses somethting else, but what and how does that work for betas? This needs documentation *somewhere* because it currently does not exist. I would be the happiest person if this didn't need an answer, but alas, despite having perfectly fine working tools to build sites, with Drupal 8 we need to use composer and most modules are in beta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work because the "stable preference" of composer is not a preference but a hard choice which you can *not* override with anything except specifying an exact version.

If you have `"prefer-stable": true,` in your `composer.json` then the only way to install a beta module is `composer require  'drupal/bricks:2.0.2-beta2'`. Neither `2.0.*@dev` nor anything else will work except that.

Switching that setting off with `composer config prefer-stable false` is possible but it might affect other modules.

You can check why composer refuses to do what you tell it to do -- because of course it does -- with `composer why-not drupal/bricks:2.0.2-beta2`.

Answer (score 14):

This installs the latest beta-12 for me:

```
composer require drupal/webform:5.0.*@dev
```

You need to do a bit of translation from the Drupal version number. From [Using Composer to manage Drupal site dependencies](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-manage-drupal-site-dependencies):

> Specifying a version you can specify a version from the command line with:
>
> ```
>  $ composer require drupal/<modulename>:<version>
> ```
>
> For example:
>
> ```
>  $ composer require drupal/ctools:3.0.0-alpha26
>  $ composer require drupal/token:1.x-dev
> ```
>
> In these examples, the composer version 3.0.0-alpha26 maps to the drupal.org version 8.x-3.0-alpha26 and 1.x-dev maps to 8.x-1.x branch on drupal.org.
>
> If you specify a branch, such as 1.x you must add -dev to the end of the version.

Hence for Webform, 8.5 becomes 5.0.x, and that's what you need to use to identify the package correctly.

Comment: This doesn't work. `composer require  'drupal/bricks:2.0.*@dev'` goes `Downgrading drupal/bricks (2.0.2-beta1 => 2.0.1)` , I just released 2.0.2-beta2.

Comment: Works fine for me and plenty of others, check the rest of your configuration

Comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/307335/69441